# Turn off autocompletion without affecting session history caching

Tags: html, autocomplete, browser-history

I would like to

(1) not show any suggestions to the user while typing in an input field.

This can be done like this:

```
<input autocomplete="off">
```

However, I noticed that this also

(2) disables the history chaching, e.g. when you go to another site and click on the history back button the input field will be empty.

You can try it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/LC53F/

Only text inserted into the first field will survive going to a new page and back again.

Is there a way to only have effect (1), but not (2)?

Comment: Did you solve this? Struggling with the same issue. Quite annoying. @Daniel

Answer (score 0):

**This solution should work, but is not ideal: just sharing an idea.**

I don't think you will be able to preserve history with 'autocomplete', so let's try to fiddle out something.

Here's an idea: the history is based on input names, so you can turn off the autocompletion from other sites by using an uncommon name (but still constant, for example: 'email_fakeSuffix_194h5g48').

Then, to turn off autocompletion from this input previous values, you can change its name everytime the page is loaded (ie. append a random number). The problem is that, doing this, you will also turn off the history.

So, **the main idea is to use an uncommon input's name and to change it just before submitting the form**:

- The value won't be saved by the browser because the name has changed
- If you navigate to another page without submitting, the value will
  still be set because you haven't change the name yet.

Here's an example using JQuery (you can use anything else, or even vanilla JS)

***JSFiddle***: http://jsfiddle.net/vse9jx3r/

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input id="input1" name="email_fakeSuffix_194h5g48">
    <input name="input2">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    $('#input1').attr('name', 'email_fakeSuffix_194h5g48_' + Date.now());

    //SUBMIT THE FORM (MAY DO NOTHING AT ALL)

});
```

You can tell me if I'm not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (using jQuery 1.9.1):

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type=text]').prop('autocomplete','off');

    $('#formid').on('submit', function(e){
        $('input[type=text]').removeProp('autocomplete');
    });
});
```

Comment: Does this address both aspects of the original question?